# jquery each | increment variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, each

I have a variable ( object ) which contain several values.

For each of those values I execute an AJAX with "post" and "done" method as followed.

Could you please help me to understand why the variable "counter" is well incremented in the loop ( first console.log show, 1, 2, 3 ,4, ....).

But when the loop ends, the second "console.log" show "counter" at 0 ? Did I missed something ?

```
$('.confirm_suppression').on('click',function(){
    var counter = '0';
    $.each(row_to_delete, function(data){
        $.post(
            "/mysql/function_manager.php",
            {
                'type_request' : 'remove_user_from_host',
                'user_id' : iduser,
                'host_id' : row_to_delete[data].id
            },
            "json"
        ).done(function(data) {
            var array = JSON.parse(data);
            if(array.status == 'OK'){
                ++counter;
                console.log('value counter in loop : ' + counter);
                $('#dialogboxhead').val('in progress');
            };
            if(array.status == 'KO'){
                alert(array.msg);
            };
        });
    });
    console.log('value counter : ' + counter);
});
```

`

Thank you.

Comment: Each time through the loop, you start off a `post()` call, which will end sometime later. Then the loop exits, with counter (oddly) `'0'` instead of just `0`. Sometime later, the `post` calls complete, incrementing `counter` as they do.

Answer (score 2):

Because you doing a asynchronous task with  `$.post`, called an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call. That means that `done()` part is called, if the AJAX call is done. While this AJAX call takes some time the rest of the function is executed. So this part `console.log('value counter : ' + counter);` is called before this part `console.log('value counter in loop : ' + counter);`.